# Using UseRouter.query Values in Content with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes

I am currently learning routing in Next.js and I'm unable to find a reason why the following code isn't including the query values in the html response. I realize isReady is not true and the return is happening without the variables being set but I'm unsure how to wait for them to be set before returning

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';

const Thread = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const queries = router.query;
  let communityName;
  let threadName;

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(router.isReady) {
      communityName = queries['community-name'].replaceAll('-', ' ');
      console.log(communityName)
      threadName = queries['thread-name'].replaceAll('-', ' ');
      console.log(threadName)
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  return <h1>Hello from the {communityName} Forum!<br /><br />You're receiving the thread named {threadName}!</h1>
};

export default Thread;
```

I'm hitting 'http://localhost:3000/test/forum/Test-Thread' and returning the following:

```
Hello from the Forum!

You're receiving the thread named !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the basics of React. `useEffect` runs after the render is complete. If you change anything in `useEffect` and want that to reflect in the UI you have to trigger a state change.

`communityName` and `threadName` should be state variables.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';

const Thread = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const queries = router.query;
  const [communityName,setCommunityName] = useState('');
  const [threadName,setThreadName] = useState('');


  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(router.isReady) {
      setCommunityName(queries['community-name'].replaceAll('-', ' '));
      setThreadName(queries['thread-name'].replaceAll('-', ' '));
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  return <h1>Hello from the {communityName} Forum!<br /><br />You're receiving the thread named {threadName}!</h1>
};

export default Thread;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did have to adjust the line to import to the following but the rest works and makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the help!

Edit: 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';